# Is run() method synchronous in Python 3.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in Python. I have written following program and expecting all the threads to work in parallel while they are working sequentially. Can you please suggest where is the problem:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.2

# Import required libraries
import sys
import threading
import time

# Scan command line arguments
noOfThreads     = int( sys.argv[1] )

# Initialize an array for storing thread IDs
threadList = [ None ] * ( noOfThreads + 1 )

# Define a class Fast which implements threading
class Fast( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__( self, threadId ):
        self.threadID = threadId

    def run( self ):
        print( "P(" + str( self.threadID ) + ") sleeping" )
        time.sleep(5)
        print( "P(" + str( self.threadID ) + ") entering CS" )
        # CS
        print( "P(" + str( self.threadID ) + ") exiting CS" )

# Initiate and run the threads
for thrId in range( 1, noOfThreads + 1 ):
    threadList[ thrId ] = Fast( thrId )
    threadList[ thrId ].run()
```

O/P of the program when run with with 3 threads:

```
P(1) sleeping
P(1) entering CS
P(1) exiting CS
P(2) sleeping
P(2) entering CS
P(2) exiting CS
P(3) sleeping
P(3) entering CS
P(3) exiting CS
```

Comment: Start your threads with `start()`, not `run()`.

Comment: Thanks. So, that means start() is asynchronous while run is synchronous.

Comment: You can look at it that way -- `run()` is just a regular method, nothing special happens when you call it. `start()` makes sure `run()` executes in a different thread.

Comment: @isbadawi You should make that an answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that this `start` vs. `run` distinction is also exactly how it works in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to start a thread call its `.start()` method. Never call `.run()` explicitly
- you forgot to call parent `.__init__()` method

You don't need to create a `Thread` subclass to use threads; a simple function will do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread

def task(tid):
    print("P({}) sleeping".format(tid))
    time.sleep(5)
    print("P({}) entering CS".format(tid))
    # CS
    print("P({}) exiting CS".format(tid))

# Scan command line arguments
thread_count = int(sys.argv[1])

threads = [Thread(target=task, args=(tid,)) for tid in range(thread_count)]
for t in threads:
    t.daemon = True # die if the program exits
    t.start() # start the thread

# wait for completion
for t in threads: t.join()
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/vADTl)

```
P(0) sleeping
P(1) sleeping
P(2) sleeping
P(2) entering CS
P(2) exiting CS
P(0) entering CS
P(0) exiting CS
P(1) entering CS
P(1) exiting CS
```

btw, if `task()` is CPU bound you could do `from multiprocessing import Process as Thread` to consume multiple cores (using multiple processes instead of threads).